# Flutter - Animate untapped widget on tapping widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful class BottomBarWidget as follows

```
class BottomBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      const BottomBarWidget({
        Key? key,
        required this.item,
        required this.isSelected,
        required this.iconSize,
        required this.onItemSelected,
        required this.index,
        required this.selectedIndex,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      final ShakingBottomNavigationBarItem item;
      final bool isSelected;
      final double iconSize;
      final ValueChanged<int> onItemSelected;
      final int index, selectedIndex;
    
    
      @override
      State<BottomBarWidget> createState() => _BottomBarWidgetState();
    }
    
    class _BottomBarWidgetState extends State<BottomBarWidget>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      late AnimationController animationController;
      // late Animation<double> shakeAnimation;
      late Animation<Color?> colorAnimation;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        animationController = AnimationController(
          vsync: this,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
        );
    
        // shakeAnimation = TweenSequence(<TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
        //   TweenSequenceItem<double>(
        //     tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: -0.7),
        //     weight: 60,
        //   ),
        //   TweenSequenceItem<double>(
        //       tween: Tween<double>(begin: -0.7, end: 0), weight: 20),
        //   TweenSequenceItem<double>(
        //       tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 0.5), weight: 20),
        //   TweenSequenceItem<double>(
        //       tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.5, end: 0), weight: 10),
        // ]).animate(
        //   CurvedAnimation(
        //     parent: animationController,
        //     curve: Curves.ease,
        //   ),
        // );
    
        colorAnimation = ColorTween(
          begin: widget.isSelected ? widget.item.selectedColor : widget.item.inactiveColor,
          end: widget.isSelected ? widget.item.inactiveColor : widget.item.selectedColor,
        ).animate(animationController);
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        animationController.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final int indexToBeMoved = widget.selectedIndex;
        return AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: animationController,
            builder: (BuildContext context, _) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  print(indexToBeMoved);
                  widget.onItemSelected(widget.index);
                  // animationController.forward();
                  // Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 700),(){
                  //   animationController.reset();
                  // });
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: widget.iconSize * 2,
                  width: widget.iconSize * 2.5,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Transform.rotate(
                        angle: 0,
                        // angle: shakeAnimation.value,
                        child: IconTheme(
                          data: IconThemeData(
                            size: widget.iconSize,
                            color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          child: widget.item.icon,
                        ),
                      ),
                      // const SizedBox(
                      //   height: 3,
                      // ),
                      // widget.isSelected
                      //     ? Container(
                      //         height: 10,
                      //         width: 35,
                      //         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      //           color: widget.item.selectedColor,
                      //           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      //         ),
                      //       )
                      //     : const SizedBox(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    }
```

I have implemented it as

```
child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: items.map(
            (bottomBarItem) {
              var index = items.indexOf(bottomBarItem);
              return BottomBarWidget(
                item: bottomBarItem,
                isSelected: index == selectedIndex,
                iconSize: iconSize,
                onItemSelected: onItemSelected,
                index: index,
                selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
              );
            },
          ).toList(),
        ),
```

What I am trying to do is to animate the BottomBarWidget of index 0 and 1 if BottomBarWidget of index 2 is clicked, animate index of 1 and 2 if BottomBarWidget of index 0 is clicked and animate index of 2 and 0 if BottomBarWidget of index 1 is pressed.